Which set is generally bigger in a group $G$? Is it $Z(G)$ or $C_G(g)$ for $g \in G$?
Here, $Z(G)$ is the center of the group G and $C_G(g)$ is the centraliser of the element $g$ in group $G$. I am confused about which set being more constrained as for a set, as I am going with this ideology that if the set has more constrained conditions then the number of elements in that set are generally less. Is $Z(G)$ keeping more constrained on the elements of $G$ as it accounts for every element of $G$ or $C_G(g)$ is more constrained as it accounts only for one element of $G$? Hopefully the term "generally" is relevant in the question too. My main confusion here is how to know which is constrained further.

Generally the centralizer of a particular element is strictly larger than the center of a group. The centralizer of a particular element is the set of elements of the group which commute with that particular element, but the center of the group is the set of elements which commute with every element of $G$, so these elements are constrained further.
Another way to convince yourself is to note that the center is the intersection of individual centralizers:
$$
Z(G) = \bigcap_{g\in G}C_G(g),
$$
which is clearly a subset of any particular centralizer, and generally speaking this can be a strict subset of particular centralizers.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

Elements in the centre commute with all group elements. In particular, they commute with $g$. This shows $\operatorname{Z}(G) \subseteq \operatorname{C}_G(g)$. In particular, the centraliser contains at least as many elements as the centre.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

In a group $G$, the center $Z(G) = \{ z \in G \mid zg = gz \text{ for all } g \in G \}$ consists of elements that commute with every element of $G$. The centralizer $C_G(g) = \{ x \in G \mid xg = gx \}$ contains elements that commute specifically with one element $g$. Since $Z(G) \subseteq C_G(g)$, it follows that $|Z(G)| \leq |C_G(g)|$.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
